# Forumula to create Table of Content in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula which can directly be used in cells to read all the active tabs' name. Please refer the screen shot for the same[image].

There is also a **=MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1,255)** formula, but it is only giving the current tab name.
Though this is easily possible using macro, but would be great if can get formula for that.

Comment: What does all Active tabs mean? All visible? All tabs within the workbook?

Comment: I may be not correct in my words, but by "Active tabs", I mean all available tabs in a sheet which are visible

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this through formula's only,

Have a look [here](http://www.thesmallman.com/list-all-sheet-names-formula/)

It feels a bit double to post exactly how it's done, but the approach makes use of a `named range` and a `lookup formula`

It's fairly easy to do

Comment: Thank you. It's working and pretty much. I am just trying to understand how the formula is working.

Answer (score 1):

I note you say formula but you could use a very simple [User Defined Function](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx) (UDF) which goes in a standard module in the VBE (which you open with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>)

```
Option Explicit
Public Function GetTabName(ByVal tabIndex As Long) As String
    GetTabName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tabIndex).Name
End Function
```

The sheet index gets passed into the UDF as a parameter and the associated sheetname is returned.

---

[image: Data]

---

If testing for visible sheet you could use the following, which has additional handling for sheet not found:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function GetTabName(ByVal tabIndex As Long) As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo Errhand
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tabIndex)
    If ws.Visible Then
        GetTabName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tabIndex).Name
    Else
        GetTabName = "N/A"
    End If
Errhand:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9
            GetTabName = "Sheet not found"
        End Select
    End If
End Function
```

---

[UDF Limitations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel)

---

Comment: ? I didn't even know it was possible to write your own worksheet function or write your own worksheet functions, the so-called "user defined function" or "user defined functions". (Adding this comment for reference purposes)

Comment: Yes you can. I have added some links. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @QHarr Thank you for sharing the UDF concept. Though I tried using it, but getting some error. May be I am not clear on the UDF aspect. And thanks again for sharing the UDF link. I will go through this and learn more about UDF.

Comment: You open the visual basic editor, goto project explorer > right click add standard module (not class) > add code. In the sheet call the function as shown in diagram e.g. in a cell put  =GetTabName(1)